# How to make multi line rich text field readonly

Tags: jquery, html

None of the following code will change my multi line rich text field to be readonly (on an update form). The column name is Log.

```
$("textarea[id^='Log'] body").attr('readonly', true);
$("input[id^='Log'] body").attr("readonly",true); 
$($("[id^=Log][id$=inplacerte]")[0]).children().attr("readonly", true);
$($("[id^=Log][id$=inplacerte]")[0]).attr("readonly", true);
$("[id^=Log][id$=inplacerte]").attr("readonly", true);
$("[id^=Log]").attr("readonly", true);
```

The html that results looks like this

```
 <div class="ms-rtestate-field ms-rtefield ms-inputBox ms-inputBoxActive" id="Log_e060111e-51d4-491f-be4d-eeb4f4f18bc0_$TextField_topDiv" readonly="readonly">
   <div id="Log_e060111e-51d4-491f-be4d-eeb4f4f18bc0_$TextField_inplacerte_label" style="display: none;" readonly="readonly">Rich text editor Log</div>
   <div class="ms-rtestate-write ms-rteflags-0 ms-rtestate-field" id="Log_e060111e-51d4-491f-be4d-eeb4f4f18bc0_$TextField_inplacerte" role="textbox" aria-labelledby="Log_e060111e-51d4-491f-be4d-eeb4f4f18bc0_$TextField_inplacerte_label" style="min-height: 168px;" contenteditable="true" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-multiline="true" readonly="readonly" RteDirty="false">
      <div class="ExternalClassFDC8776178884911AD86361735106BB4" readonly="readonly">
        Field text entered here <br> aSasAS s ss s s 
        <span id="ms-rterangecursor-start" aria-hidden="true" RteNodeId="1">
        </span>
        <span id="ms-rterangecursor-end" aria-hidden="true">
        </span>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div style="clear: both;">
   </div>
</div>
```

Looking at the html, you can see readonly set to readonly everywhere, but I can still edit the field. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Bonanza...

The code

```
$($("[id^=Log][id$=inplacerte]")[0]).attr("contenteditable","false");
```

Did the trick.

Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Then mark it so the question goes to the answered list

Comment: Excellent piece of code. Works like a charm!

Comment: **Note:** the field id differs, so you should use f12 to get the correct one as mentioned at [Set Rich Multiple Line Text Field as Read Only in SharePoint](http://itcore.devoworx.net/read-only-rich-multiple-line-text-field-in-sharepoint/)

Answer (score 0):

Because the `readonly` attribute is only for `input` tags

[image]

It is the `contenteditable` attribute that makes a `div` tag editable

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable

Comment: I've just tweaked that field to be false, and am getting a general SP error SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error.
sp.ui.rte.js (2,232445)